# shell script: while read line No such file or directory

Tags: shell

I have a simple problem to resolve.  Count number of delimiters for each line in a file.

Here is my sample file:

```
4489201,6421,,,
4619802,4276
```

I want to count how many commas in each line.  I wrote this while read line script, but keep getting an error "No such file or directory"

```
#!/bin/bash
data_file="$1"

while read line
do 
    delimiter_cnt=`sed 's/[^,]//g' $line | wc -c`

echo "delimiter_cnt"
done < $data_file
```

The error message is:

```
sed: can't read 4489201,6421,,,,,,,,,: No such file or directory
0
sed: can't read 4619802,4276,,,,,,,,,: No such file or directory
0
```

I would really appreciate your help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: With `bash`, you can avoid the `echo` in Greg Hewgill's answer using the `<<<` operator:  `sed 's/[^,]//g' <<< "$line" | wc -c` and you don't even need to capture and echo the output if that's all you do with it.

Answer (score 5):

You are asking `sed` to read a file by that name. Try sending your input to `sed`'s stdin:

```
delimiter_cnt=`echo $line | sed 's/[^,]//g' | wc -c`
```

Comment: This works beautifully.  I really appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to "accept" the answer that helped you the most by clicking on the checkbox to the left of the answer (this helps other people by clearly showing the best answer to your question). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

use awk:

```
awk -F, '{print NF-1}' < input_file
```

By `-F,` you say awk, to use `,` as a field separator, and then for each line print `NF-1` value. `NF` is a number of fields in `awk` for the current record.

Answer (score 1):

I like [Michał Šrajer's awk answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745003/shell-script-while-read-line-no-such-file-or-directory/7745082#7745082). If you use bash, you can do it right in the shell:

```
while read line; do
    commas=${line//[^,]/}
    echo ${#commas}
done < filename
```